# C# Too many characters in character literal

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Please tell me what i'm wrong in my code

```
void EnkripsiCitra()
    {
        string kuncis = Convert.ToString(textBox2.Text);
        string [] key = kuncis.Split('(?<=\\G.{3})');

        int [] kunciVigenere= new int[600];
        int k=0;

        for (int i=0; i<600;i++)
        {
            kunciVigenere[i]=Convert.ToInt32(key[i]);

        }
```

the problem is --> string [] key = kuncis.Split('(?<=\G.{3})');
how to fix it? please help me

Comment: Why are you converting a string to string? The single quotes `' '` define characters, you should use double quotes `" "` to define a string (I'm talking about the `Split`'s parameter).

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because single quotes define a single character (e.g. `'a'`) whereas double quotes define a string (e.g. `"hello"`).

Your next issue is that C# doesn't do Regex like that. Instead there's a dedicated [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace. Something like this should do the split you desire:

```
Regex test = new Regex("(?<=\\G.{3})");
string[] keys = test.Split("123456");
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

See a fiddle [here](http://rextester.com/VTX84114).

Comment: Thanks for this answer John and thanks for not machine gunning Muhammad with downvotes for being a newbie to C#.

Comment: @Daniel I normally would (not for being a newbie, but not using Google first), but this had more problems than just a simple "you should be using double quotes", which I felt warranted a response :)